# Diakrites land wrong in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-12c

Every time we are rolling out a new release same tables are trancated and filled with fresh data. This process is done on a Windows pc with scripts that are run in SqlPlus.

When we do this on our development environment the diakrites are inserted as upsidedown questionmarks (¿) in stead of (ä, ë, ï or ö).

If the data is insert by hand in PL/SQL Developer the data is inserted in the right way. Because of the great amount of data this is not exceptable to do every time. It is also not possible to do this in the acception and production database.

I have tried to find some solution for this problem on the internet, but cloud not find it.  Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: NLS settings?  OS character set? Is the file a UTF8 file?

Comment: Most likely your NLS_LANG setting is incorrect. When you run your SQL script - presumably a long list of inserts - there is no way for the database server process to know which character set you use for the strings: you have to tell it explicitly. On Windows, that is done via a registry key (called NLS_LANG). The value looks something like this: GERMAN_GERMANY.WE8ISO8859P1. The last word (WE8ISO8859P1) is the name of the character set used by your script. You need to find out what it is and specify that.

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind, you can set `NLS_LANG` also as Environment variable. The Environment variable takes precedence over the Registry setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sqlplus inherits the encoding from calling `cmd.exe` codepage. You must tell Oracle which codepage is used with `NLS_LANG` value. Value of `NLS_LANG` and used codepage have to match.

Try this:

```
c:\>chcp 1252
Active code page: 1252

c:\>set NLS_LANG=.WE8MSWIN1252

c:\>sqlplus ...
```

Note, if you run sql-files then ensure they are saved as "ANSI" (i.e. CP1252 for "Western" Windows). If you use a different encoding then set chcp and `NLS_LANG` accordingly, for example:

```
c:\>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

c:\>set NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8

c:\>sqlplus ...
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600